# Resuming Lottie Animation on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, lottie

The Lottie animation restarts on orientation. Is there any way to resume it from where it stopped in the Portrait mode. This is my current code for Lottie animation view.

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/hello_world" />
```

Comment: You can save the animation progress in 'onSavedInstance' on set it again using '                animationView.playAnimation(0.5f,1f)'  // Resume your animation from 50% to 100%

Comment: How to get the current animation progress from LottieAnimationView?

Comment: Use 'animationView.progress' or 'animationView.getProgess()'